# Leak in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I have been pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this is leaking. In my .h file I have a synthesized property nonatomic, retained NSMutableArray. In my viewDidLoad I declare it as:

```
self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.tableData removeAllObjects];
fillData(self.tableData);
```

Throughout my application, I call [self.tableData removeAllObjects] and then repopulate it with the fillData(self.tableData) function. This function fills up the data from a static C++ string set:

```
void fillData(NSMutableArray* list)
{
    for (set<string>::const_iterator itr = sortedData.begin(); itr != sortedData.end(); ++itr){
        [list addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", ((string)*itr).c_str()]];
    }
}
```

In my dealloc method I do:

```
[self.tableData removeAllObjects], [self.tableData release], tableData = nil;
```

Where did I drop the ball? Instruments says it's in the [list addObject....] line.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't your `((string)*itr).c_str()` call return a string which isn't autoreleased?

Comment: Yes but that is copied over to an NSString which should be released automatically. So I'm not sure how this is causing a leak. Do I need to alloc/autorelease that NSString instead?

Comment: Looks fine. What happens if you split the line into two, separating it into  `const char*s=(*itr).c_str(); [list addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];` ?

Comment: By the way, using `@"%s"` in `stringWithFormat:` is discouraged, because you can't specify the encoding used, which is very dangerous. It can suddenly stop working in a Russian iPhone, say. Use `stringWithUTF8String:` or `stringWithCString:encoding:error:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.tableData removeAllObjects];
fillData(self.tableData);
```

+1 retain for `alloc`, +1 retain for using the property's setter. You haven't balanced the +1 from `alloc`. If you are going to use the setter:

```
self.tableData = [NSMutableArray array];
fillData(self.tableData);
```

Note that `removeAllObjects` in that is completely pointless.

This is odd, too:

```
[self.tableData removeAllObjects], [self.tableData release], tableData = nil;
```

First, don't bother removing the objects.  When the array is deallocated, it'll release all objects.   Secondly, using the setter to call `release` and then immediately do a direct assignment is inconsistent.  Either do:

```
self.tableData = nil;
```

Or:

```
[tableData release], tableData = nil;
```

(Note that the use of the `,` in all of this is also purely for your benefit -- it has no impact on generated code.)

Also, use `stringWithUTF8String:` and not `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's *the* leak, but this looks like it's a problem:

```
self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You say that `tableData` is a property that's retained. Try:

```
self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

That way the property retains it and the array itself is autoreleased. Your release in `dealloc` will bring the retain count back down to zero.

Comment: Don't bother with `arrayWithCapacity:` unless you know *exactly and always* how many items there will be.  Even then, it is largely just clutter in the code and provides no real world advantage of any import.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your property is set as retain, and you set it to an already retained object.
You should do it like this:

```
// viewDidLoad
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.tableData = array;
[array release]; // this is important

// dealloc
self.tableData = nil; // will automatically release the array
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dealloc, you use properties which retain the tableData again. That is not really what you want, so do:

```
[tableData release];
```

or

```
[self->tableData release]; // not necessary, but some prefer it.
```

or

```
self.tableData = nil; // property will handle release
```

No need to clear the tableData, no need to set anything to nil (you are deallocating, so nothing will access it anymore).